# All components/modules in my Angular2+ app now erroring with "No provider for Router"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have updated my basic app to have routing via app.routing.ts, but since this update all of my test files have errors claiming no Router is provided.

I can quash the errors with `imports: [RouterTestingModule]`, but is there a way I can globally import this?

I tried to import it in `app.module` to no resolution.

Comment: can you add some more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do it in a global way. You have to import it in the `TestingModule`

```
    beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [RouterTestingModule],
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of :-(
Thanks for clarifying

Comment: in 6 minutes ;-)